# I want to get a callback function's variable another function

Tags: node.js

**coin.js**

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('userfile'), function(req, res){

  var filename = __dirname +'/'+ req.file.path;

  var s = fs.ReadStream(filename);
  s.on('data', function(data) {
    shasum.update(data)
  })
  s.on('end', function() {
    var hash = shasum.digest('hex') //this var
    console.log("Hash : "+ hash + '  ' + filename)

    fs.unlink(filename, function (err) { //파일제거
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('successfully deleted '+ filename); });

    res.send('Uploaded : ' + hash + "           " + filename);
  })
})

app.get('/stampid', function(req, res){
  client.stampDocument(hash, function(err, stampId) { //i want to call hash
      res.render('coin2', {si:stampId})
  });
})
```

I have a this code, then I want to call a var 'hash' in the function below.

I don't know what to do, I want fixed code.

I need your help.

Comment: Could you please  error messages and entire code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

use global variable :

```
var hash;  // <----- declare it here

app.post('/upload', upload.single('userfile'), function(req, res){

  var filename = __dirname +'/'+ req.file.path;

  var s = fs.ReadStream(filename);
  s.on('data', function(data) {
    shasum.update(data)
  })
  s.on('end', function() {
    hash = shasum.digest('hex') //this var
    console.log("Hash : "+ hash + '  ' + filename)

    fs.unlink(filename, function (err) { //파일제거
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('successfully deleted '+ filename); });

    res.send('Uploaded : ' + hash + "           " + filename);
  })
})

app.get('/stampid', function(req, res){
  client.stampDocument(hash, function(err, stampId) { //i want to call hash
      res.render('coin2', {si:stampId})
  });
})
```

Comment: hash will be undefined if `app.get('/stampid', ...` runs before `app.post('/upload', ...`